# Array rotation in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, rotation

In MATLAB, is there a way to rotate the elements of a array to another dimension, like:

```
y=[-1,0,1] -->  y=[-1; 0; 1] (like transpose)

y=[-1,0,1] -->  y(:,:,1)=-1, y(:,:,2)=0, y(:,:,3)=1 

y=[-1,0,1] -->  y(:,:,1,1)=-1, y(:,:,1,2)=0, y(:,:,1,3)=1
```

I would like to avoid for loops.

Answer (score 5):

You can do these sorts of matrix operations using [transposition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html), the function [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html), or the function [PERMUTE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/permute.html). For example:

```
y = [-1 0 1];               %# Your 1-by-3 sample array

y2 = y.';                  %'# Transposing y gives you a 3-by-1 array
y2 = reshape(y,[3 1]);      %# This also gives you a 3-by-1 array
y2 = permute(y,[2 1]);      %# This also gives you a 3-by-1 array

y3 = reshape(y,[1 1 3]);    %# This gives you a 1-by-1-by-3 array
y3 = permute(y,[3 1 2]);    %# This also gives you a 1-by-1-by-3 array

y4 = reshape(y,[1 1 1 3]);  %# This gives you a 1-by-1-by-1-by-3 array
y4 = permute(y,[4 1 2 3]);  %# This also gives you a 1-by-1-by-1-by-3 array
```

Answer (score 3):

While reshape and permute are more powerful tools, you can solve the given example quite easy with:

```
y = [-1 0 1];
y2(:,1)=y;
y3(1,1,:)=y;
y4(1,1,1,:)=y;
```

Comment: +1 for another viable solution. However, this one is limited in that it only works if you are assigning to a *new* variable. If you wanted to place the reshaped result back into the old variable `y`, like `y(1,1,:) = y;`, you will get an assignment error. RESHAPE or PERMUTE would be needed in such a case.